# using System.Web.Script.Serialization is not working for some reason why?

Tags: .net, using, javascriptserializer

I have created a .ashx.cs class and in this class I am using SqlConnection to retrieve data from a stored Procedure table in Sql server, Now after getting the data i want to Serialize the data into json but its not leeting me using

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = New javaScriptSerializer(); //Cant use this
```

so when I try to import the necessary using statement

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // this will not import for reason.
```

" Error: The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace "

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I was able to solve it on my own so basically System.Web.Extensions assembly was the missing part but you do Not add this in your project directly but..

To add the assembly, right-click on your project (in the solution explorer) and select "Add Reference". System.Web.Extension should be listed under the .Net tab.